# Detecting events from a bluetooth remote shutter to control audio recording in Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, bluetooth, shutter

I need to use a bluetooth remote shutter as the ones that come with many selfie sticks in order to make a push-to-talk button for starting and stopping audio recordings in Python. I have tried using pyBluez module (vs 0.21), but the most I have got is to detect the device and its address, but I cannot see which are its services, or how to create a client-server connection with it. 
Checking the bluetooth connector status, I can see that it detects the device as "i Shutter" and its type as keyboard. The device is already paired. In case, it is relevant I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.

Comment: Have you looked at `rfcomm-server.py`? It looks like it would expect that it just receives data once it is paired and the socket has been opened?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. But the connection is never done. I have also tried scanning for the device using _italic_ hcitool scan _italic_ but sometimes the device is not even detected. It is like after few seconds the shutter just go off. I also replaced the batteries but the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the selfie sticks use HID profile (confirmed as "type keyboard"), and send a Volume Up button press (keyboard report or consumer report). You will need to listen for this key, and not RFCOMM data.